# How to configure the triggers for my laptop's keyboard backlight?

Tags: keyboard, dell, backlight

I want my keyboard backlight to be generally disabled and glow only when I do a manual Fn-key toggle.

The problem is that I can not find a way to edit the files - `trigger` and `start_triggers` in `/sys/devices/platform/dell-laptop/leds/dell::kbd_backlight`

I can edit the `brightness` and `stop_timeout` by using

```
echo ... | sudo tee ...
```

but not these.

The laptop is Dell XPS 2015 Developer Edition FHD.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the keyboard backlight brightness using <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F10</kbd> (of <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F10</kbd>, if <kbd>Fn</kbd> is inverted). In particular, you can set brightness to zero :)

If you need to change the timeout for backlight automatically to switch off, use the file

```
/sys/devices/platform/dell-laptop/leds/dell::kbd_backlight/stop_timeout
```

Comment: I am already doing it. But, it gets on again after certain triggers - typing after some hiatus, resume, unlock etc..
As asked, I want to disable these triggers.